# Obtain a readable data from DER ApplicationSpecific object

Tags: java, bouncycastle, der

I have problem to parse a `p7m` file into a `CMSData`. After I passed the file into an `ASN1InputStream`, I get:

> DER ApplicationSpecific[13]
>   (4b596567594a4b6f5a496876634e415163436f494b59617a43436d47634341514578447a414e42676c67686b67425a514d4541674546414443436b5955474353714753496233445145)

and with same procedure for obtain contents this became:

> DER ApplicationSpecific[8]
>   (6143436b585945677046795044393462577767646d567963326c76626a306e4d5334774a79426c626d4e765a476c755a7a306e53564e504c5467344e546b744d53)

Finally, I obtain octets format using `getContent()` method but I can't go on because the `number of attempts to retrieve the content` or using `ASN1Primitive getObject()` gives me this error:

> java.io.EOFException: DEF length 93 object truncated by 63

I would just like to get the readable content, which should be an `.xml` file.

The Inputstream of a `.p7m` file with a `non readable content`:

> MIKYegYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIKYazCCmGcCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCCkYUGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCkXYEgpFyPD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0nMS4wJyBlbmNvZGluZz0nSVNPLTg4NTktMScgc3RhbmRhbG9uZT0neWVzJz8+CjwhLS0gQzpcdXNyTG9jXDAxXEVzc2VMb2NhbGUxOTRcVGVtcEZQMDAxXEZhdHR1cmUuWE1MIC0gZ2VuZXJhdGVkIGJ5IEFDVUNPQk9MLUdUIHY5LjIuMiArIEVDTi00Mjg

Any help is welcome, it is a long time that I can't solve and I have to `manually extract the contents with dyke6` .

```
    ASN1InputStream newStream = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayIS));
                System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(newStream, true));
                DERApplicationSpecific app = (DERApplicationSpecific) newStream.readObject();
                System.out.println(app.toString());
                System.out.println(app.getApplicationTag());
                System.out.println(app.isConstructed());
                System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(app, true));  
                newStream.close();
                byte[] decode = Base64.decode(app.getContents());
                String s = new String(decode, "UTF8");
                System.out.println(s);
                ASN1InputStream contents = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decode));
                app = (DERApplicationSpecific) newStream.readObject();
                System.out.println(app.toString());
                System.out.println(app.getApplicationTag());//13
                System.out.println(app.isConstructed());
                System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(app, true));
                decode = Base64.decode(app.getContents());
                s = new String(decode, "UTF8");
                System.out.print(s);
                contents = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decode));
                app = (DERApplicationSpecific) contents.readObject();
                System.out.println(app.toString());
                System.out.println(app.getApplicationTag());//8
                System.out.println(app.isConstructed());//true  
//Fino a qui sembra tutto ok
                byte[] cont = app.getContents();//Ottengo gli "octets"
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<cont.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(cont[i]);
                }
                //decode = Base64.decode(app.getContents());//org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.DecoderException: unable to decode base64 data: Index -92 out of bounds for length 128
                /*s = new String(decode, "ISO-8859-1");
                System.out.println(s);*/
                s = new String(cont, "UTF8");
                System.out.println(s);//¤]? ¤\?Þ?\?Ú[Û?IÌK? È[?ÛÙ//UTF8:?]? ?\???\??[?I?K?  ?[???
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: @Heri Sorry for code

Comment: `MIKYegYJK...` is  not a valid pkcs#7 object.